# Double showing a lot of zeros with printf

Tags: c++, integer, printf, double, calculator

I wanted to write a little calculator, which I have already done by using `cout` and `cin`, and I used `double` instead of `int` to not only get integers as an output.

At school, I then saw that we're going to use `printf()` and `scanf()`. To practice the new commands, I wanted to rewrite my program, but when I run my program I only see a lot of zeros after the comma as an output. Does anybody know why?

I wanted to rebuild a calculator with `double` instead of `int` to not only get integers as a result.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    printf ("Taschenrechner\n\n");
    int zahl1, zahl2;
    char rechop;
    double erg;
    
    printf ("Gib die Rechnung ein: ");
    scanf ("%d", &zahl1);
    scanf ("%c", &rechop);
    scanf ("%d", &zahl2);
    
    if (rechop == '+'){
        erg = zahl1+ zahl2;
        printf ("Ergebnis: ");
        printf ("%f", erg);
    }
    else if (rechop == '-'){
        erg = zahl1 - zahl2;
        printf ("Ergebnis: ");
        printf ("%f", erg);
    }
    else if (rechop == '*'){
        erg = zahl1 * zahl2;
        printf ("Ergebnis: ");
        printf ("%f", erg);
    }
    else if (rechop == '/'){
        erg = zahl1 / zahl2;
        printf ("Ergebnis: ");
        printf ("%f", erg);
    }
    else {
        printf ("Keine gültige Rechenoperation!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include the input, output and expected output in the question.

Comment: Any specific reason why you're using `printf()` in c++?

Comment: @RichardCritten The user should be able to type in one number, than what he wants to do (+,-,*,/) and then the second number. Depending what he wants to do it should add, subtract, mutiply or divide the given numbers.

Comment: @Luki *Does anybody know why?* -- Maybe the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) would be helpful?  If you're going to use something new, that's the first step -- read the manual.

Comment: Not directly related but if you can use C++20, stop using printf, start using std::format.
(printf is from a security point of view not a safe function)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'd really like to use cout and cin because I think that it's easier to use but my teacher says that we have to use printf instead of cout so I have to relearn it.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I have to use printf because of school.

Comment: In my book a good teacher would accept a better solution  ;) You can tell him someone who used C++ since 1995 said so ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yeah I also told him that but our school isn't very modern and I don't think they will change that.

Comment: @Luki -- Why not write a very simple, two line `main` program that practices how to use `printf` properly?  Once you get that to work, then you apply it to a larger program.

Comment: @Luki sorry to hear that, and yes sometimes you just have to go with the flow :(

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yeah :(

Comment: My guess would be `scanf` is failing, please show a [mre] with the input and expected output

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We already wrote a much simpler calculator at school, but I was sick on that day so I couldn't see what they were doing and I already watched a few videos on printf and my problem but I can't find a solution.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'm sorry that I have to ask but what is a minimal reproducible example? :(

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes but I don't know what I could improve or shorten in my program because I don't know how to use printf properly yet.

Comment: Show the input to your program and what you expect the output to be

Comment: Should I send a screenshot or what?

Comment: I mean my program is written in german if that's going to be a problem (the text etc.)

Comment: Too many people are excluded when you use images and the question becomes harder to search. Never use a screenshot as an important source of information on stack overflow unless the question is about a graphics programming problem or you need to show exactly how you have configured a GUI dialogue. If the image is of code, text output, or an error message, you've excluded a lot of people who could have helped and future programmers who could learn from the question.

Comment: **`printf` is NOT the problem here.**  You are calling it correctly.

Comment: Just copy and paste the text from the terminal, no need to take a screenshot

Comment: @user481301 thanks for telling me how to use this platform correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

To decide how many decimal numbers show, you can use `%.2f` (where ".2" stands for "2 decimals after the comma") in the printf instead of simply `%f`.

**Edit:** forgot to say that, by doing that, your result get rounded (and not simply "cut").

There is your code updated (and translated):

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    printf ("Calculator\n\n");
    int num1, num2;
    char simbol;
    double res;
    
    printf ("Insert the expression: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num1);
    scanf ("%c", &simbol);
    scanf ("%d", &num2);
    
    if (simbol == '+'){
        res = num1+ num2;
        printf ("Result : ");
        printf ("%.2f", res);
    }
    else if (simbol == '-'){
        res = num1 - num2;
        printf ("Result : ");
        printf ("%.2f", res);
    }
    else if (simbol == '*'){
        res = num1 * num2;
        printf ("Result : ");
        printf ("%.2f", res);
    }
    else if (simbol == '/'){
        res = num1 / num2;
        printf ("Result : ");
        printf ("%.2f", res);
    }
    else {
        printf ("Not a valid expression!");
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I translated it using google translate to make it more readable to everyone.

Comment: thanks for showing me how to use the % symbol. I'm going to try your code today and let you know if it solved my problem.

Comment: Although it didn't solve my problem I learned how to round so thank you :)

Comment: Actually I misunderstood the question. I published a new answer, hope it helps. If there’s any problem don’t be afraid to ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your output has zeros after the decimal point, because that's actually what is in the variable (`erg`) that you are printing.

Your problem is that this line uses integer division:

```
erg = zahl1 / zahl2;
```

When the compiler is picking which operation to do, it only looks at the data type of the inputs (which are both `int`).  The result is then converted to be stored into `erg`, but that doesn't affect the division behavior chosen.

Change the line to:

```
erg = zahl1 * 1.0 / zahl2;
```

or

```
erg = zahl1;
erg /= zahl2;
```

so that one of the inputs will be type `double`, and integer division will no longer be involved.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what the problem is I'm going to change it and let you know if i that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you’re doing operations between `int` (num1 and num2 are declared as `int`). In order to have decimal numbers you must do operations between float (or double as in your case).

You can declare `num1` and `num2` as `double` directly (and change `%d` to `%lf` in the `scanf` and `printf`).

Another possibility is to do an **explicit** **type cast**: type cast is basically a conversion from a type to another and it is explicit because you’re writing it instead of letting the compiler do it for u (in your og program a cast is done by the compiler, after the operation, to fit the `int` result in the `double` type variable `erg`).

So an example is:

```
result = num1 + num2;
```

Becomes:

```
result = (double)num1 + (double)num2;
```